# Scrape two separate chart and merge into one by beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I tried to scrape the BoxOffice Chart in this website and got stuck in making two separate chart into one DataFrame. (Idk why it has separated but those should be merged in one identical Chart)

`URL: https://www.the-numbers.com/box-office-records/worldwide/all-movies/cumulative/released-in-2019`

When it comes to having two separate chart but doesn't include any specific code name for each one, How can I deal with the columns?

When I scrape the column using `soup.select('table>thead>tr>th')`, **it shows double times, so I just want to cut the column in front of repetition**.

example.

```
Columns: [Rank, Movie, Worldwide Box Office, Domestic Box Office, International Box Office, DomesticShare, Rank, Movie, Worldwide Box Office, Domestic Box Office, International Box Office, DomesticShare]


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

URL = "https://www.the-numbers.com/box-office-records/worldwide/all-movies/cumulative/released-in-2019"

rq = requests.get(URL)
soup = bs(rq.content,'html.parser')

columns=soup.select('table > thead > tr > th')

columnlist=[]
for column in columns:
    columnlist.append(column.text)
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columnlist)

contents=soup.find_all('table')
contents=soup.select('tbody > tr')

dfcontent=[]
alldfcontents=[]

for content in contents:
    tds = content.find_all('td')
    for td in tds:
        dfcontent.append(td.text)
        alldfcontents.append(dfcontent)
        dfcontent=[]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columnlist)
```

This is what I would like to make as a DataFrame:

```
Columns: Rank, Movie, Worldwide Box Office, Domestic Box Office, International Box Office, DomesticShare
Factors: 1, Avengers Endgame, ... 
         ...
         100, ~, ...
```

so that hopefully I can use it to machine learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Read url
URL = "https://www.the-numbers.com/box-office-records/worldwide/all-movies/cumulative/released-in-2019"
data = requests.get(URL).text

#parse url
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

#find the tables you want
table = soup.findAll("table")[1:]

#read it into pandas
df = pd.read_html(str(table))

#concat both the tables
df = pd.concat([df[0],df[1]])

df

  Rank       Movie                              Worldwide Box OfficeDomestic Box Office International Box Office    DomesticShare
0   1   Avengers: Endgame                           $2,615,368,375         $771,368,375 $1,844,000,000              29.49%
1   2   Captain Marvel                              $1,122,281,059         $425,152,517 $697,128,542                37.88%
2   3   Liu Lang Di Qiu                             $692,163,684               NaN      $692,163,684                NaN
3   4   How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World  $518,846,075          $160,346,075   $358,500,000              30.90%
4   5   Alita: Battle Angel                         $402,976,036           $85,710,210   $317,265,826              21.27%
5   6   Shazam!                                     $358,308,992           $138,067,613 $220,241,379               38.53%
```

This should do what you want, you just have to concat the 2 tables together after reading the correct html tag with pandas.